# How to clear and refresh a coach in IBM BPM using script?

Tags: javascript, ibm-bpm

I'm working on a process in IBM BPM. In my coach I have a form with search and clear buttons. Search will be done using two string fields and a date while the result is a list. In clear script I defined a new instance of all variables in the form. for first time search is working but after pressing the clear button, search result is not correct. Any idea how can I clear my form or refresh it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to do the following:

1. Bind the variables to the controls in coach view.
2. On click of clear button, attach a script in which you set these value to nothing. For example, if the variable is string set it as `tw.local.somevariable = ""`.
3. Route back from script to coach.

I think this will work.

Apart from that, for your error, please check the values of the variable in debug mode.